# How to programmatically determine if my iMessage app extension is enabled from main app?

Tags: ios, imessage, imessage-extension

In the iOS Messages App Store users have the ability to control which extensions are 'added' and available to use from the iMessage Extension tray. If the app extension is not 'added' the user cannot use it and does not see as an option in their extension tray while typing a message.

I have a main app that includes an iMessage extension app.

My question is, if I have a main app that also contains an iMessage extension, how can I/can I programmatically determine what this preference is for my extension from within the main application?

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/) and a look into the [Messages framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages) doesn't mention this ability but perhaps there is way someone knows?

Comment: AFAIK, you can not.

Comment: I need to know this too.   I want to prompt the user to install it, if not already installed.